# What is the difference between "I am sorry to miss your concert" & "I am sorry for missing your concert"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Here is from [the dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sorry_1?q=sorry)

> **Sorry** (adj): [not before noun] feeling sad and sympathetic
>
> sorry (that)… I'm sorry that your husband lost his job.
>
> sorry (to see, hear, etc.) We're sorry to hear that your father's in
>   hospital again.
>
> sorry (about something) No one is sorrier than I am about what
>   happened.
>
> **Sorry** (adj): [not before noun] feeling sad and ashamed about something
>   that has been done
>
> sorry (about something) We're very sorry about the damage to your car.
>
> sorry (for something/doing something) He says he's really sorry for
>   taking the car without asking.
>
> sorry (that)… She was sorry that she'd lost her temper.
>
> If you say you're sorry we'll forgive you.
>
> **Sorry** (adj): [not before noun] feeling disappointed about something
>   and wishing you had done something different or had not done something
>
> sorry (that)… She was sorry that she'd lost contact with Mary.
>
> You'll be sorry if I catch you!
>
> sorry to do something I was genuinely sorry to be leaving college.

[This site](http://masterkeyenglish.com/to-be-sorry-to-vs-to-be-sorry-for/) says:

> When do we use **to be sorry to** and **to be sorry for**? Have a look
>   at the following sentences, it´s really easy!
>
> To be sorry to + infinitive = to apologise for a **present** action
>
> *I´m sorry to interrupt but could you come with me for a second?*
>
> To be sorry for + verb with -ing = to apologise for a **past/earlier**
>   action
>
> *I´m sorry for lying to you, I won´t do it again*

I would say:

"**I am sorry to miss your concert**" means I'n sorry **before** I do it

"**I am sorry for missing your concert**" means I'm sorry **after** I did it

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct and that you answered your own question.

Answer (score -1):

> "I am sorry to miss your concert" means I'm sorry before I do it
>
> "I am sorry for missing your concert" means I'm sorry after I did it

Almost! "I'm sorry *to miss* your concert" is in the present, not the future. If the concert is happening right now, and you are missing it, then this is correct.

From your example:

> I'm sorry to interrupt but could you come with me for a second?

If someone says this, they are interrupting *at the present moment*; they're not apologizing for interrupting in the future.

I don't think there's a nice single preposition you can use for the future. If the concert is in the future, I'd say "I'm sorry that I will miss your concert".

You can also use "I'm sorry that" with any verb tense:

> I'm sorry that I *will miss* your concert.
>
> I'm sorry that I *am missing* your concert.
>
> I'm sorry that I *missed* your concert.

Many native speakers drop "that" and just say "I'm sorry I..."

Happy apologizing! :)

Comment: As a native English speaker, I would say, “I’m sorry to miss your concert,” to talk about a future event, and I find this fully grammatical. Also, “Sorry I’m missing your concert,” which feels slightly more casual.